# Processing 3, video lib: could not load movie file Ubuntu

Tags: ffmpeg, processing, ubuntu-16.04, video-library

Don't sample code video lib processing 3.3.6 on Ubuntu 16.04. File in both folder - with sketch and data folder. Previous Install gstreamer 0.10-ffmpeg (solved previous problem with not run lib)  Any your idea? 
P.S. Work on Windows 7

```
import processing.video.*;

Movie mov;

void setup() {
  size(640, 360);
  background(0);
  mov = new Movie(this, "transit.mov");
  mov.loop();
}

void movieEvent(Movie movie) {
  mov.read();  
}

void draw() {    
  image(mov, 0, 0);

  float newSpeed = map(mouseX, 0, width, 0.1, 2);
  mov.speed(newSpeed);

  fill(255);
  text(nfc(newSpeed, 2) + "X", 10, 30); 
}
```

Best Regards,
Kos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, all.
I found solution: I install gstreamer-plugin-good and this fix this.
I don't understand why previous install just gstreamer 0.10 don't help

Thanks to https://github.com/processing/processing-video/issues/52

Comment: You should [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so the question is not marked as needing an answer.